# The way to index multi-lingual content by Lucene?

Tags: lucene

I have an APP supporting search based on lucene.

or other method to support both Chinese and English searching?

Answer (score 0):

Hello I don't totally understand your question but I think I have a rough idea of what you want to achieve.

If you want to search for languages separatly, I would suggest you to add a Lucene Field "Language" at index time. According to the language of the text you are indexing.

Since you can easily differentiate Chinese characters from english caracters using

Character.UnicodeBlock:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.UnicodeBlock.html

For example you want to check char 1 of the String "str":

```
if(Character.UnicodeBlock.of(**str[1]**) == Character.UnicodeBlock.CJK_UNIFIED_IDEOGRAPHS)
{ do something }
```

This way at search time you can detect chinese input the same way and add a condition on your language field to the query.

Now if you want to have a mixed search I would suggest to build your custom Analyzer that analyzes each word and stores a translation for it in your index.